# Python help: Globally defined item keeps yielding not defined error

Tags: python

PSA: Python learner (30 days and counting).
I am trying to create a python script which creates a playlist of videos which are randomly selected from given folder/sub-folder. When I run it, I get a "'selected_files' is not defined" error in line 40 (in the "# create a VLC playlist in select folder" section) of my script, when I have clearly defined it globally...I think. Welcome the assist.

```python
import os
import random
    
def find_files(folder, extensions):
    files = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            if any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions):
                files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return files

def main():
    global selected_files
    # specify the folders to search and the file extensions to search for
    folders = [r"path\to\show1", r"path\to\show2", r"path\to\show3", r"path\to\show4"]
        
    extensions = (".mp4", ".avi", ".mkv")

    selected_files = []
    for folder in folders:
        files = find_files(folder, extensions)
        if files:
            selected_files.append(random.choice(files))
        else:
            print(f"No files found in {folder}.")
    if not selected_files:
        print("No files found.")
        return
    
# create a VLC playlist in select folder
playlist_folder = r"path\where\playlist\is\saved"
if not os.path.exists(playlist_folder):
    os.makedirs(playlist_folder)
playlist_file = os.path.join(playlist_folder, "PMTV.xspf")
with open(playlist_file, "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
    f.write('<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">\n')
    f.write('\t<title></title>\n')
    f.write('\t<trackList>\n')
    for file in selected_files:
        f.write('\t\t<track>\n')
        f.write(f'\t\t\t<location>{file}</location>\n')
        f.write('\t\t\t<title></title>\n')
        f.write('\t\t\t<duration></duration>\n')
        f.write('\t\t\t<extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">\n')
        f.write('\t\t\t\t<vlc:id></vlc:id>\n')
        f.write('\t\t\t</extension>\n')
        f.write('\t\t</track>\n')
    f.write('\t</trackList>\n')
    f.write('</playlist>\n')
print(f"{len(selected_files)} files added to {playlist_file}")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You mean block 1 sub def 3 where selected _files is defined? I want the selected_files here to refer to everything I put in def main () folders=["blah1....blah2....blah3...etc].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Hannu and Chepner. Don't have commenting privileges, yet (newbie on SuperUser) so I'll post what I did as an answer.

I made two changes, which solved the riddle:

```
#1) Define folders in main ()
    def main():
     folders = folders = [path\to\show1, path\to\show2...yada...yada...yada...]

#2) Localize selected_files
    selected_files = []
        for folder in folders:
            files = find_files(folder, extensions)
            if files:
                selected_files.append(random.choice(files))
```